# $lookup no db.createView()

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, nosql

Tenho uma banco de dados com duas *collections*: `companies` e `people`.

E quero criar uma *view* chamada "peopleSectors" a partir da `collection people`.

```
db.createView (
   "peopleSectors",
   "people",
   [
     { $lookup: { from: "companies", localField: "company_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "company_field" } },
     { $project: 
          { "_id": 0, 
            "first_name": 1, 
            "last_name": 1, 
            "job": 1,  
            "company": '$employer', 
            "sector": /* aqui mora o problema */
          }
     }
   ]
)
```

Porém dentro de `$project`, quando crio o *schema* da *view*, quero que o seu campo `"sector"` seja igual ao campo sector da collection companies dentro do $lookup.

Como acesso essa `collection`? Sei que para acessar *collection* base da *view*, basta colocar o `dollar` na frente, mas e a outra?

Exemplo Schema - "people"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d7a121fa937f710a7d486e"),
    "last_name" : "Pham",
    "quote" : "Aliquam est reiciendis alias neque ad.",
    "job" : "Counselling psychologist",
    "ssn" : "401-31-6615",
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Burgessborough",
        "street" : "83248 Woods Extension",
        "zip" : "47201"
    },
    "first_name" : "Yvonne",
    "company_id" : ObjectId("57d7a121fa937f710a7d486d"),
    "employer" : "Terry and Sons",
    "birthday" : ISODate("2011-03-17T11:21:36Z"),
    "email" : "murillobrian@cox.net"
}
```

Exemplo Schema -  "companies"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d7a121fa937f710a7d486d"),
    "sector" : "Wholesale",
    "name" : "Terry and Sons",
    "mission" : "implement frictionless systems",
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Lake Meaganton",
        "state" : "Idaho",
        "street" : "211 Diane Shoals",
        "zip" : "10914-3394"
    },
    "logo" : "http://dummyimage.com/687x376"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada etapa da agregação, recebe o resultado da anterior.
Sendo assim, basta usar [dot-notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) para acessar o campo desejado.

Tente algo como por exemplo:

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "companies",
      localField: "company_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "related_companies"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "first_name": 1,
      "last_name": 1,
      "job": 1,
      "company": '$related_companies.name',
      "sector": '$related_companies.sector'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Perfeito! Tinha tentado usar o "$" no nome do campo `as`, mas por algum motivo não tinha funcionado. Só uma coisa, sei que está fora do escopo da pergunta, mas é que os resultados de `company` e `sector` na view saem como *arrays* de um único item. Como faço para saírem em *strings* soltas?

Comment: Você pode adicionar mais uma fase no pipeline de agregação.
`{$unwind: "$related_companies"}`.

Assim, para cada elemento do array, será retornado um documento. Como o campo é um ID, imagino que só vai haver um de cada mesmo.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Funcionou... ^^